# [R6030]How to initialize C Run Time from assembly code?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to run the following simple assembly code which uses CRT function `printf`.

```
.386
.model flat, c
Sleep proto stdcall arg1:DWORD  
printf proto c printlist:vararg 

.data
strformat db "%s", 0Ah, 0
string1 db "Starting..",0
string2 db "Wait 5 seconds..",0
string3 db "Finishing..",0

.code
main:
    invoke printf, addr strformat, addr string1
    invoke printf, addr strformat, addr string2
    invoke Sleep, 5000
    invoke printf, addr strformat, addr string3
    ret
end main
```

Compiled and linked using:

```
ml /c /coff temp.asm
link /subsystem:console temp.obj kernel32.lib libcmt.lib
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error.

```
runtime error R6030 - CRT not initialized
```

If I link it with `msvcrt.lib`, it works fine. The problem is with static version of CRT. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to reverse engineer the initialization as it's done in C(++) projects. Static library initialization may change in the new versions, so, why not just use the DLL?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - Thanks. I just want to know why dll version works and static version doesn't. All I (a newbie) can assume is that msvcrt.dll is already in the memory when my program runs, so my program doesn't need to do any initializations and in static version this isn't the case.

Comment: Most likely the DLL initializes itself when it loads. DLLs have a special function for that very purpose, somewhat similar to `main()` in C/C++ EXEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> end main

That syntax sets *main* as the entry point of your program.  You want to write plain "end" so the linker uses the default entrypoint (mainCRTStartup).  And make your main function public so the linker can find it.  Like this:

```
.code
public main
main proc
    ; etcetera
    ret
main endp
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my problem. But how come `msvcrt.lib` work properly ?

Comment: Because msvcrxx.dll was designed to initialize the CRT when the DLL gets loaded.  Please close your question.